# x86 Interrupt handler not reacting

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt-handling

I have a small bootloader that prints Hello World on the screen. I want to modify it so that it changes the written message when a key is pressed. I set up an IDT with one entry (the second one) that should call my handler. However I get no response.

I got the values for selector and type_attr of the entry from some website, I am still not entirely sure if they are correct and how they work.

This is the relevant code:

```
typedef unsigned int   uint32_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef unsigned char  uint8_t;

#define VID_PTR 0xb8000
#define ROWS 25
#define COLS 80
#define IDT_SIZE 256

struct IDTDescr {
    uint16_t offset_lower;
    uint16_t selector;
    uint8_t zero;
    uint8_t type_attr;
    uint16_t offset_upper;
};

struct IDTDescr IDT[IDT_SIZE];

void write_string(const char *string) {
    char *vid_ptr = (char *) 0xb8000;
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while (i < ROWS * COLS * 2) {
        vid_ptr[i] = ' ';
        vid_ptr[i+1] = 0x07;
        i += 2;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (string[i] != '\0' && i < ROWS * COLS) {
        vid_ptr[2*i] = string[i];
        i += 1;
    }
}

void callback() {
    write_string ("Hello Keyboard!");
    __asm__ ("iret");
};

void setup_interrupt() {
    /* Write IDT */
    uint32_t callback_address = (uint32_t) &callback;
    IDT[0x1].offset_lower = callback_address & 0xffff;
    IDT[0x1].selector = 0x08;
    IDT[0x1].zero = 0;
    IDT[0x1].type_attr = 0x8e;
    IDT[0x1].offset_upper = (callback_address & 0xffff0000) >> 16;

    write_string((char *) 0x100000);

    /* Load IDTR */
    struct __attribute__((packed)) {
        uint16_t length;
        uint32_t base;
    } IDTR;

    IDTR.length = IDT_SIZE * sizeof(struct IDTDescr) - 1;
    IDTR.base = (uint32_t) &IDT;
    __asm__ ( "lidt (%0)" : : "p"(&IDTR) );
}

int kmain(void __attribute__((__unused__)) *foo, uint32_t __attribute__((__unused__)) bar) {
    write_string ("Hello World!");
    setup_interrupt ();

    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: I don't see where you enabled interrupts. PS: Simply sticking `iret` into your code won't work either, and unless you disable timer you will need a handler for that too.

Comment: And yes, you obviously need to provide a default handler for all the other interrupt vectors and enable interrupts with `asm("sti");` when you're ready, and clear the mask on the PIC after handling IRQs or they won't fire again.

Comment: @tux3 IRQ 1 is only IDT 33 if you set it up like that. It isn't by default, and I don't see any code that does that either.

Comment: @Jester "It isn't by default", isn't it, thought ? The first 32 vectors are reserved. Vector 1 is the Debug exception. On a stock qemu/bochs system and on my laptop, without any special setting up, the PS/2 keyboard gets vector 33 (irq 1)

Comment: It isn't. Since real mode interrupt vectors expect that, the interrupt controller is set up like that. Switching to protected mode does not magically change the interrupt controller configuration, you have to do that yourself. See the [osdev.org page](http://wiki.osdev.org/PIC#Protected_Mode).

Comment: @Jester Well, I somehow managed to always have it work on several computers, VMs and emulators without remapping anything. Perhaps that's one of the things GRUB does for you. Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: Actually osdev says the default offset is `8h` for `PIC1` and `70h` for `PIC2`, so by default IRQ1 generates interrupt 9. Just checked in qemu, it is true. So you identified a problem correctly :)

Comment: @Jester how did you check this so quickly?

Comment: I have answered [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27756452/interrupts-causing-kernel-to-reset) recently. I used that code and commented out the IRQ remapping :)